# store ftp command output in a variable

Tags: bash, ftp

I am using bash a script to connect to an FTP server for deleting a file.
I would like to  store the output message and code of the `delete` command executed on the FTP server into a variable of my script.

How could I do this ?

Here is my snippet :

```
...
function delete_on_ftp{
  ftp -i -n $ftp_host $ftp_port <<EOF
quote USER $ftp_login
quote PASS $ftp_pass
delete $1
quit
EOF
}
output_cmd=$(delete_on_ftp $myfile)
...
```

By the way I do above I only get the message, no way to get the returned code. Is there another way allowing to get the code and the message, in 1 or 2 variables ?

Thanks, Cheers

Comment: What is the output you get when you run the script and when you do the FTP manually? Are you're looking for something like `250 Delete operation successful.`?

Comment: Yes, `echo "$output_cmd" | grep '250 DELE command successful'` should return 0 (which is the errorlevel) if the operation is done successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the following curl command, which make your task easy.

```
curl --ftp-ssl -vX "DELE oldfile.pdf" ftp://$user:$pass@$server/public_html/downloads/
```

Please do not forget the slash at the end of your directory, it is necessary.

```
curl: (19) RETR response: 550
```

550 oldfile.pdf: No such file or directory

```
curl: (19) RETR response: 250
```

250 DELE command successful

curl is available at http://curl.haxx.se/.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to get FTP to act automatically is to use a *Netrc* file. By default, FTP will use `$HOME/.netrc`, but you can override that via the `-N` parameter. The format of a `netrc` file is fairly straight forward. A line is either a Macrodef or a line that contains login information. Here's an example below:

### Netrc File

```
mysystem login renard password swordfish
another login renard password 123456
default login renard password foofighter

macdef init
binary
cd foo
get bar
delete bar
quit

macdef fubar
...
```

The three first lines are the logins for various systems. The `default` is a login for any system which you don't define a particular login for. The lines that start with `marcodef` are macros you define to do a series of steps for you. The `init` macro automatically runs right after login. If the last line is `quit`, it will quit out of FTP for you. There should be a blank line to end the macro, (although most systems will take an End of the File as the end of the macrodef too).

You can create a *Netrc* file on the fly, enter your FTP command in that, and then, run your FTP command with that *Netrc* file:

```
cat > $netrc_file <<<EOF
$ftp_host login $ftp_login password $ftp_password
macdef init
delete $my_file
quit
EOF

ftp -N $netrc_file
```

You can capture the output via STDOUT, or in a variable and then parse that for what you need:

```
ftp -N $netrc_file | tee $ftp_output
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers on this question should provide you what you want.

However, if you are keen on specifically using `ftp` command, you can use [`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) command for the same...
Note, that this is not the best way to achieve what you are trying.

```
expect -c "log_user 0;
           spawn ftp -i -n $ftp_host $ftp_port;
           expect \"<add ftp login username: prompt details here>\"
           send \"quote USER $ftp_login\r\n\"
           expect \"<add ftp login password: prompt details here>\"
           send \"quote PASS $ftp_pass\r\n\"
           expect \"<add ftp shell prompt details here>\"
           log_user 1; send \"delete $1\r\n\"
           log_user 0;
           expect \"<add ftp shell prompt details here>\"
           send \"quit\r\n\";
           interact"
```

You may need to add some more lines in the above for the login & shell prompts returned by the ftp command.